# When I boot I just get this: error file ‘/boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic’ not found

Tags: boot, error-handling

I’ve tried many different things so I need some help! Thanks!

*Update:
The output of ls -l /boot is:

```
mint@mint:~$ ls -l /boot
total 4858
-rw------- 1 root root 4736015 Apr 20 16:33 System.map-5.4.0-26-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  237718 Apr 20 16:33 config-5.4.0-26-generic
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root      60 Sep 30 19:35 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      27 Jun 24 18:38 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      27 Jun 24 18:38 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun 24 18:38 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun 24 18:38 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /boot` ?

Comment: @PJSingh I updated the post with the info.

Comment: How did you make this output for `ls -l /boot`? You seem to be able to boot one of the older kernels while grub is configured for a later one. Depending on what you did earlier, I'd try `sudo apt update` `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. If that (re-)installs 5.4.0.-28 or later, you'll be OK. If you do not get a kernel, try `sudo update-grub`. Please port your results.

Comment: @Adriaan I have the a Linux mint 20 usb installer and I ran the command through that. But then I realized I could restore my system with timeshift! It worked like a charm! So I’m good now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t now why I didn’t think of this before, but I could just use timeshift to restore my system! Yay! All fixed now!